# Android gps/network getting current location

Tags: android, gps, location

I have this code for receiving LatLng of current location of the user in my app
it works fine most of the time until i turn on gps, it stops working then and goes onto the part of the code which says that no provider is enabled and redirects to a location, i have tried many fixes, this is my best so far, but it is still really bad, i cant figure out a fix.

```
       public static LatLng getCurrentLocation(final Context context)
        {
                LocationManager locMgr = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                String locProvider = locMgr.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                Location location = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(locProvider);

                if(location != null) return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                boolean isGPSEnabled = locMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                boolean isNWEnabled = locMgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                Criteria criteria2 = new Criteria();
                criteria2.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
                criteria2.setCostAllowed(true);

                if (locMgr != null) {
                    location = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(locMgr.getBestProvider(criteria2, true));
                    if(location == null) {
                            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                            location = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(locMgr.getBestProvider(criteria2, true));
                            if(location != null) return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    } else 
                        return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                }

                if(isNWEnabled) {
                    if (locMgr != null) {
                        location = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if(location != null) return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());}
                } 
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                     if (locMgr != null) {
                            location = locMgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if(location != null) return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()); }
                }
                if (location == null){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No location provider activated, using saved location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("MyApp_Settings", 0x0);
                    String uLa = settings.getString("LATITUDE", "");
                    String uLo = settings.getString("LONGITUDE", "");
                    double lat = 0 ;
                    double lng = 0 ;
                    if (!(uLa.equals(""))) {
                        lat = Double.parseDouble(uLa);
                        lng = Double.parseDouble(uLo);
                        return new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    } else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        builder2.setTitle("Location");
                        builder2.setMessage("No Location Services Enabled, Do You Want to Open Location Settings?");
                        builder2.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                context.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));    
                            }
                         });
                        builder2.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                         });
                        builder2.show();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Using Random Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return new LatLng(34, -94);
                    }                   
                }
/*                if(location == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Using Random Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return new LatLng(34, -94);
                } */
                return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()); 
        }
```

i am looking for suggestions to improve this code and fix the gps provider

Comment: would this method be better for receiving current location?
https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: the above didnt work either